# Set column order in sequelize.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to put `user_id` column before the timestamps, how can i tell this to `sequelize.define`?

```
sequelize.define('UserPassport', {
    method: DataType.STRING,
    token:  DataType.STRING,
    social_id: DataType.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        UserPassport.belongsTo(models.User);
      }
    },
    tableName:   'user_passports',
    underscored: true
  });
```

schema of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_passports` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `method` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `token` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `social_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
      `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
      `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `user_passports_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

P.S: is it possible to make a composite key out of `method` and `social_id` so they both would compose the PK instead of the id field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is just to add it in `define` stage wherever you want, like so:

```js
var user_passport = sequelize.define('user_passport', {
    method: DataTypes.STRING,
    token: DataTypes.STRING,
    social_id: DataTypes.STRING,
    user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
            user_passport.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
        }
    },
    tableName: 'user_passports',
    underscored: true
});
```

and in `associate` attach a reference to the field:

```js
user_passport.belongsTo(models.settings, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
```